# Amazon SES mail not getting sent using nodemailer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, nodemailer

Trying to use amazon ses for my website to send emails through my website. My app is developed using nodejs and sending mails using nodemail & nodemailer-ses-transport. But getting the following error.

```
{ AccessDenied: User `arn:aws:iam::755682848022:user/shajao.email' is not authorized to perform `ses:SendRawEmail' on resource `arn:aws:ses:us-east-1:755682848022:identity/shajao.com'
    at Request.extractError (/Volumes/Zotac 120GB/6sense/printit/printit-backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/query.js:47:29)
    at Request.callListeners (/Volumes/Zotac 120GB/6sense/printit/printit-backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)
    at Request.emit (/Volumes/Zotac 120GB/6sense/printit/printit-backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
    at Request.emit (/Volumes/Zotac 120GB/6sense/printit/printit-backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
    at Request.transition (/Volumes/Zotac 120GB/6sense/printit/printit-backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/Volumes/Zotac 120GB/6sense/printit/printit-backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /Volumes/Zotac 120GB/6sense/printit/printit-backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Volumes/Zotac 120GB/6sense/printit/printit-backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Volumes/Zotac 120GB/6sense/printit/printit-backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/Volumes/Zotac 120GB/6sense/printit/printit-backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)
    at Request.emit (/Volumes/Zotac 120GB/6sense/printit/printit-backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
    at Request.emit (/Volumes/Zotac 120GB/6sense/printit/printit-backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
    at Request.transition (/Volumes/Zotac 120GB/6sense/printit/printit-backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/Volumes/Zotac 120GB/6sense/printit/printit-backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /Volumes/Zotac 120GB/6sense/printit/printit-backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Volumes/Zotac 120GB/6sense/printit/printit-backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Volumes/Zotac 120GB/6sense/printit/printit-backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/Volumes/Zotac 120GB/6sense/printit/printit-backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)
    at callNextListener (/Volumes/Zotac 120GB/6sense/printit/printit-backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:95:12)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/Volumes/Zotac 120GB/6sense/printit/printit-backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:269:13)
    at emitNone (events.js:110:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:207:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1059:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
  message: 'User `arn:aws:iam::755682848022:user/shajao.email\' is not authorized to perform `ses:SendRawEmail\' on resource `arn:aws:ses:us-east-1:755682848022:identity/shajao.com\'',
  code: 'AccessDenied',
  time: 2017-12-25T10:49:05.129Z,
  requestId: '39942938-e961-11e7-aa22-07070e500047',
  statusCode: 403,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 32.881228690068795 }
```

My code is as follows:

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(sesTransport({
        accessKeyId: SESCREDENTIALS.accessKeyId,
        secretAccessKey: SESCREDENTIALS.secretAccessKey,
        rateLimit: 5
    }));


    var mailOptions = {
        "from": "Shajao Customer Service<admin@shajao.com>",
        "to": to,
        "subject": subject,
        "text": text,
        "html": html
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, cb);
```

created user in IAM in aws console and added my access key id and secret id. But still isnt working. not sure how to add `ses:SendRawEmail\'

Answer (score 3):

You need to put a policy or role for your user in IAM:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
    {
       "Effect": "Allow",
       "Action": ["ses:SendEmail", "ses:SendRawEmail"],
       "Resource":"*"
     }
    ]
 }
```

IAM -> Users -> your user (shajao.email?) -> add inline policy